# Struggling with git submodule and django

Tags: django, git, git-submodules

I have a django project A which contains an app App1. I also have a django project B in which I'd like to have the same App1. Then, when I edit App1 in my project A, I'd like to update App1 and be able to pull changes in project B.

A and B are under separate git repository.
What should be my workflow?
Should I create a submodule and a new git repo for the App1 I want to duplicate? I read a lot about people struggling with submodules and tricking git...

I don't want to break anything...

Cheers

Comment: What about ``subtree``? http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

Comment: I'm having a look, I have no knowledge in that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my question was pretty stupid. I created a separate git repo for App1. I create a new directory on my computer where I copy/paste my App1 then sync it to git. Then, for each of my django project, I created git submodule and here it is!